# Can't deploy Django app on Python Anywhere: ImportError: No module named 'environ'

Tags: deployment, pythonanywhere

Trying to deploy local Django project on Python Anywhere, but receiving an ImportError: No module named 'environ' when running "python manage.py migrate"

```
File "/home/Dude1983/surfapp/src/surfapp/settings/development.py",line 1, in <module>
from .base import *             # NOQA
File "/home/Dude1983/surfapp/src/surfapp/settings/base.py", line 45,in <module>
import environ
ImportError: No module named 'environ'
```

I've checked the Django versions, both 1.9.5.

My wsgi.py looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/Dude1983/surfapp/'  # use your own username here
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'surfapp.settings.production'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

I'm using the Edge 2 starter template and my settings are located here:

```
surfapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── logger.py
    │   ├── settings
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── base.cpython-35.pyc
    │       │   │   └── development.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   ├── development.py
    │   │   ├── local.sample.env
    │   │   └── production.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
```

I have followed the DjangoGirls tutorial [here](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/).

Can anyone help me or give me any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the Edge 2 template has some dependencies that aren't installed in the default pythonanywhere system, and that one of them is called "environ".

I would suggest using a virtualenv, and then doing a

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

([the edge docs](http://django-edge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#quick-start) are a bit confusing, but they do say, or at least imply, you should be doing a "pip install" like this)

Here are the PythonAnywhere docs on using virtualenvs:

http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango